# How to save a QGIS 2.0 project template?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

When I attended the QGIS in Action workshop at FOSS4G13 Tim Sutton mentioned there was a new option to save a project as a template which when you opened up a new QGIS project you could pick to choose the saved template.

In my QGIS 2.0.1 Windows from the Project menu option there is a "New from Template" but how can I save a project as a template?

When I choose Save As... it is just a standard project file.

This may be linked with Print Composer but I have not found any guidance on using this option.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the options of QGIS 2.0 (from QGIS menu click on Settings ---> Options)  under the **General** tab, you can specify your template folder on your hardrive.
[image]

The default folder is inside your profile folder (.qgis2). To use existing qgis project files as templates (extension **.qgs**) just copy them inside the specified project templates folder. Then restart QGIS.
Now you should be able to select all the existing **.qgs** templates through the `Project -> New from Template` menu entry.